# How to replace part of a string using javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this text that needs to replace the width part of the css:

```
oldStyle = "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
```

i Have this code expression or pattern:

```
oldStyle.replace(new RegExp("width:[0-9]+%;.*$", "g"), "width:25%;")
```

But the result is:

```
"width:25%;"
```

Its missing the rest of the css:

```
"height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
```

The result should be:

```
"width:25%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
```

How do i change just the width part of the css and keep the rest of the other css intact?

Comment: Try `new RegExp("width:[0-9]+%;", "g")`

Comment: i have other code that relies on this method

Comment: @Jb31 what if it's `width:90px`?

Comment: yes i have code that takes care if its 90px i just need to understand the small part of it first

Comment: JB31 that would be ok but what if oldStyle has max-width:40%; this would change the max-width aswell

Comment: Does `(?:^|;|\s)width:[0-9]+(?:px|%)` work as a regex?

Comment: @Jb31 what if it's `width: 90cm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions for this task. There are easier alternatives.

## Basic string manipulation

Parse and manipulate the string, since it is a simple structure: semicolon separated where each segment contains a key and value separated by a colon:

```js
function changeWidth(style, newValue) {
  const segments = style
    .slice(0, -1) //remove last `;`
    .split(';');
    
  const nonWidthSegments = segments.filter(segment => !segment.startsWith("width"));
  
  return nonWidthSegments
    .concat(`width: ${newValue}`)
    .join(';')
    .concat(';'); //add the last `;`
}

console.log(changeWidth(
  "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;",  
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeWidth(
  "margin: auto;",  
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeWidth(
  "",  
  "45px"
));
```

This can be generalised to modify any property. To avoid matching the wrong property (e.g., "border-width-radius" instead of "border-width"), the `.startsWith()` is changed to provide an exact match:

```js
function changeStyle(style, property, newValue) {
  const segments = style
    .slice(0, -1) //remove last `;`
    .split(';');
    
  const otherSegments = segments.filter(segment => segment.split(":")[0].trim() !== property);
  // an exact of the property name       --->      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
  return otherSegments
    .concat(`${property}: ${newValue}`)
    .join(';')
    .concat(';'); //add the last `;`
}

console.log(changeStyle(
  "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;",  
  "width",
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "margin: auto;",  
  "width",
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "",  
  "width",
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "padding-right: 15px;border-width-radius: 10px;",  
  "border-width",
  "4px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "padding-right: 15px;border-width-radius: 10px;border-width: 10px;",  
  "border-width",
  "4px"
));
```

## DOM Manipulation

An in-memory DOM node can be created. This allows directly manipulating the style using the DOM API, which avoids potential issues when handling a string:

```js
function changeWidth(style, newValue) {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  
  el.setAttribute("style", style);
  
  el.style.width = newValue;
  
  return el.getAttribute("style");
}

console.log(changeWidth(
  "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;",  
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeWidth(
  "margin: auto;",  
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeWidth(
  "",  
  "45px"
));
```

This approach is trivial to generalise without having to handle extra cases:

```js
function changeStyle(style, property, newValue) {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  
  el.setAttribute("style", style);
  
  el.style[property] = newValue;
  
  return el.getAttribute("style");
}

console.log(changeStyle(
  "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;",  
  "width",
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "margin: auto;",  
  "width",
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "",  
  "width",
  "45px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "padding-right: 15px;border-width-radius: 10px;",  
  "border-width",
  "4px"
));

console.log(changeStyle(
  "padding-right: 15px;border-width-radius: 10px;border-width: 10px;",  
  "border-width",
  "4px"
));
```

Comment: He want to use `regexp`, not other approach

Comment: @AhmetZeybek I've found many people want to use regex because they don't know of any other way. Many *future visitors* might also benefit from understanding that regex is not a golden hammer.

Comment: @AhmetZeybek If you want a reason why I prefer to give out alternatives, then you will notice that *every single regex answer here is wrong*. It's not that regex is impossible to write correctly but it's very easy to write it *incorrectly*.

Comment: Finally i used VLAZ approach, i played around with the other suggestions using regexp, but when i added the code that VLAZ has answered it was easy to setup and integrate into my code, i have it fully working now. Thanks everyone for your suggestions but thanks VLAZ sorted it!. I will upvote the other sugesstions and answers as it helped me understand regexp a little more but this was the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This will change any value begins with `width` and ends with `%;` in your string, you can modify regexp as you wish

```js
first = "width:90%;height:100%;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
second = "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
third = "height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;width:90%;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"

console.log(first.replace(/width(.*?);/g,"width:25%;"))
console.log(second.replace(/width(.*?);/g,"width:25%;"))
console.log(third.replace(/width(.*?);/g,"width:25%;"))
```

Comment: There are [many units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Numbers_lengths_and_percentages) not just `%`. This has a very high chance of failing if the value is, say `90px`. this can be disastrous win the case of `width: 90px; height: 100%;` - the `height` property will be wiped out using this regex.

Comment: @VLAZ yes I forgot to put `?` character, now it is working without problem.

Answer (score 1):

This part `width:[0-9]+%;` will find some width value in percentage but this part `.*$` matches "*whatever it's there till the end of the string*".

But you don't want the second part to be replaced by `width:25%;`, so, just drop it:

```js
oldStyle.replace(new RegExp("width:[0-9]+%;", "g"), "width:25%;")
```

This RegExp might be improved for sure. As people correctly point out in comments, it, for instance, will also match `max-width:75%` and subsequently change it to `max-width:25%`.
However, depending on your use case it might be good enough.

Generally speaking, considering the number of things that just can go wrong, you want to avoid RegExp in situations like this until you have other choice.

Comment: There are [many units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Numbers_lengths_and_percentages) not just `%`. It's entirely possible for this to fail, especially if you et something like `width: 90%` - with a space.

Comment: @VLAZ We don't know what is the actual use case, only the author does. Somewhy *he* used % in his RegExp. Probably, he wants just values with percentage to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using the regex below. The regex will replace any width with `%` or `px` or `rem` and many other units;

```js
string = "width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
console.log(string.replace(/width ?: ?[0-9]+(%|[a-z]+|);/ig,"width:25%;"))
```

Comment: What if the unit is not `%` or `px` or `rem`? There are [many other units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Numbers_lengths_and_percentages) and it's also possible for there to e no unit. Or you might even have `width: auto`. This will fail in more cases where it succeeds.

Comment: I have updated the code, It will still work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

To replace just numerical value `width:90px;` to `width:40px;`

**or** `width:90%;` to `width:40%;`

```js
str = "max-width:40px;width:90px;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
console.log(str.replace(/([^-]width)(:[0-9]\d+)(.*)/g,"$1:25$3"))

str = "max-width:40px;width:90%;height:inherit;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"
console.log(str.replace(/([^-]width)(:[0-9]\d+)(.*)/g,"$1:25$3"))
```